# PHP child class cannot implement same interface parent class implements

Tags: php, oop, interface, extending-classes

Is it normal behavior that child class cannot implement same interface parent class implements? I got PHP v5.6

```
interface blueprint {
    public function implement_me();
}

class one implements blueprint {

    public function implement_me() {

    }

}

class two extends one implements blueprint {


}

//no fatal error triggered for class two
```

**EDIT:** So above code works great no errors or warnings even though i implemented interface `blueprint` in child class `two` without having method `impement_me()` why child class cannot implement same interface parent class implements?

if i implement another interface other than `blueprint` for class `two` then it works and i have to use `blueprint_new` methods inside class `two` otherwise fatal error triggered. This part works as intended.

```
interface blueprint {
    public function implement_me();
}

class one implements blueprint {

    public function implement_me() {

    }

}


interface blueprint_new {
    public function todo();
}


class two extends one implements blueprint_new {


}

//this will trigger fatal error.
```

Comment: From [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) I would expect multiple interfaces to be ok but not the missing `todo` in class `two`. What does the error message say?

Comment: There's no error in first example therefore i got question why child Class cannot implement same interface as parent class?

Comment: I think you misunderstand Interfaces. An Interface tells what *members* inclusive variables and respective *signatures* - need to be available in the implementing class - and those all its sub-classes have those members and implement the same interface. It does not say that you need to implement them even if they already exist. In the first example `one` implements `implement_me`, those `two` *implements it already* and the second `implements blueprint` is superfluous.

Comment: Like @makadev says, there is no problem here. Only a misunderstanding of the concept `interface`. Everything is working as it should ..

Comment: Was a bit late in the day i did not realize that method `implement_me() `was inherited from parent class `one` therefore no fatal error was triggered in the child.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The child class automatically inherits all interfaces from the parent class.

Sometimes you don't want this but you still can implement **any**, even multiple interfaces in the child class.

The only thing that does not work is to extend an interface, just like a class (or an abstract class) cannot be implemented.

The error triggered in your second code is because you didn't implement all methods from interface `blueprint_new` in class `two`, but basically there is nothing wrong in your code.

Example:

```
class MobilePhone implements GsmSignalPowered {}
class SamsungGalaxy extends MobilePhone implements UsbConnection {}
interface ThunderboltPowered {}
interface GsmSignalPowered {}
interface UsbConnection {}

$s = new SamsungGalaxy();
var_dump($s instanceof GsmSignalPowered); // true
var_dump($s instanceof UsbConnection); // true
var_dump($s instanceof ThunderboltPowered); // false

$m = new MobilePhone();
var_dump($m instanceof GsmSignalPowered); // true
var_dump($m instanceof UsbConnection); // false
var_dump($m instanceof ThunderboltPowered); // false
```